# Random image in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have 5 images in my resources folder and I would like each time I load the app to show a different image.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your XAML define an `Image` control

```
<Image x:Name="RandomImage" />
```

then in your code behind

```
// replace names with your actual names of your resources
List<string> images = new List<string> { "image1", "image2", "image3", "image4", "image5" };

// initialize RNG
var rand = new Random();
// get a random int between 0 and 4
var next = rand.Next(5);

// get the resource name
var image = images[next];

RandomImage.Source = ImageSource.FromResource(image);
```

Comment: and in XAML? :(

Comment: there's no way to do it purely in XAML

Comment: Yes, I understand, but what would I have to put in the XAML to show that function that you gave me? 
Because it appears blank

Comment: see expanded example

Comment: Thank You!... but :( Error CS1061 "Image" Does Not Contain Definition for "ImageSource" and No Extension Method "ImageSource" accepting a first argument of type "Image"   :(

Comment: typo, should just be "Source"

Comment: :( the screen is still blank, obviously it is not bringing images or maybe the images are not in the correct place, I put them in Resources / drawable

Comment: First, read the docs on using images and be sure you're doing it correctly and using the right naming conventions.  Second, try hardcoding an image name in your XAML to verify that it works.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#local-images

Comment: Thankssss Jason, I could already solve it! :)  the problem was the location of the images

Comment: @Beto If you want to do it in xaml, you can use binding.